# When is a type parameter list required to be provided?

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

What's the general rule about when a type parameter list is required?

For example, the type parameter list `<E>` seen between `static` and the return type `Set<E>` below: is it required?

```
public static <E> Set<E> union(Set<E> s1, Set<E> s2) {}
```

For another example, writing out `<E>` is not required in the `push()` or `pop()` methods below:

```
public class Stack<E> {
    public Stack();
    public void push(E e);
    public E pop();
}
```

Comment: I don't get your question. If you need a type variable, you need a type parameter list in the generic method.

Comment: Is this true for all generic method? include those defined in a generic class?

Comment: Yes, a generic class does not prevent you from writing a generic method. The types will just be unrelated.

Comment: Down vote : user failed to RTFM (read the fine manual / Documents)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this example illustrates how to use the function properly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> s2 = new HashSet<>();

    Set<Integer> result = union(s1, s2);
}

public static <E> Set<E> union(Set<E> s1, Set<E> s2) {
    // do something useful here
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that's what the question is about.

Comment: I have to admit I'm not certain either... ;-)